# Yaml error preventing me from knitting to Word document in Rstudio

Tags: ms-word, yaml, knitr

I finished a homework assignment in RStudio and wanted to knit it to a Word Doument but it stopped and gave me this error message.

```
Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : 
Scanner error: while scanning for the next token at line 2, column 7 found character that cannot start any token at line 2, column 7
Calls: <Anonymous> ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

When i look at line 2, column 7 I dont see what the problem is. Here is that chunk of code.

```
title:  "Homework Set 1"
data: `r Sys.Date()`
output:
  word_document: default
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
```

I tried to remove the space at line 2, column 7 but when I do it simply moves the error code over to another part of the same line. I dont believe its a download error or that I need to download any new programs as I just installed the program. I am unsure as to why the problem is occuring and what I need to do to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character at line 2, column 7 is `` ` ``. This character is reserved in YAML for future use and thus cannot start a scalar. You can quote the scalar to fix the error:

```yaml
data: "`r Sys.Date()`"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I implemented the fix and everything works perfectly now!